# JList setenable to false without text color change

Tags: java, swing, colors, jlist

The item in my `JList` used to be black
but when I set enable to false it became grey color. How do I maintain black color or set it back to black?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: why do you want to fool your users? Without any visual clue as to the list's disenablement they might be confused.

Answer (score 2):

The visuals of list items are completely controlled by the ListRenderer. If you really insist, subclass the default and set its enabled property to true:

```
 public Component getListCellRendererComponent(....) {
      super.getListCellRendererComponent(....);
      setEnabled(true);
      return this;
 }
```

Beware: confusing your users is never a good idea - without any visual clue that the list is disabled, they might be dioriented that f.i. selection doesn't work as expected!